# Output alignment issue

Tags: c++, c++11, format, cout, pretty-print

I am not sure how to make it align the decimal points up. Any ideas?

This code:

```
/* print the tempature at each hour 1 to 24 */
    for (int k = 0; k < day1Temps.size(); ++k) {
        cout << left << setw(20) << k << "           " << day1Temps[k] << setw(15) << " " << day2Temps[k] << endl;
    }
```

Current output:

```
Hour                           6/14/2015         6/15/2015
0                              0               0
1                              3.11               26.11
2                              4.11               27.11
3                              5.11               28.11
4                              6.11               29.11
5                              7.11               30.11
6                              8.11               30.11
7                              9.11               32.11
8                              10.11               33.11
9                              11.11               34.11
10                             12.11               35.11
/* etc */
```

Comment: Shortened output example and slightly clarified text

Comment: Well, you apparently already know how to use `std::left`. Use `std::right` in the same way.

Comment: because the table is created from one single loop using right does not seem to be working. is there a way to have dynamic spacing so that the space between the left and right collumn will adjust based on how many decimal places? right around line 7 and 8 is where the shift happens because the 10 takes up one more character then the 9 did. so it screws the second column up.